# htaccess redirects and ExpressionEngine

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, expressionengine

I just launched a new version of a site, we moved them from static files to ExpressionEngine.

I'm using the Ellis-approved htaccess method to remove the index.php from the URLs, but I also need to redirect some URLs from the old site, and I'm getting artifacts (for lack of a better term) in the redirected URLs.

For example, I have this redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /2013/atlanta/ /event/atlanta-2013
```

Which actually ends up sending you here:

```
http://aneventapart.com/event/atlanta-2013?/2013/atlanta/
```

Fortunately the page still loads correctly, but I'd much rather not have that query string in there.

Here's the snippet that removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Any help?

Comment: Note, you can post future EE questions on the beta site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert in .htaccess by any mean but, if you want all luminaries from the ExpressionEngine community to be all over your question, [post here instead on stackexchange](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/).

That being said, here is my shot at it. If you want to redirect from

```
http://aneventapart.com/2013/atlanta/
```

to

```
http://aneventapart.com/event/atlanta-2013/
```

Your 301 rule should comes before the part that removes index.php in your .htaccess. I would write such a rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^2013/atlanta/ /event/atlanta-2013/ [R=301,L]
```

Also, congrats on the redesign!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to match to sub-pages below: /2013/atlanta/something/ for example I would recommend the following

```
Redirect 301 /2013/atlanta/ http://aneventapart.com/event/atlanta-2013/
```

So do URI to full URL this will remove the basic daisychain of URIs at the end that you are seeing.

On a side note can this be moved to expressionengine.stackexchange.com public beta site?